# i have function which accepts the address,but i want to print value of the variable.. how can i do?

Tags: c, pointers

```
if (rc_avpair_add(rad_config, &send, PW_FS_RESPONSE_CODE,
                  &response_code, -1, PW_FS_PEC) == NULL)
{
    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_SESSION_LOG(session),
                      SWITCH_LOG_ERROR,
                      "failed adding Freeswitch-Response-code: %u\n",
                      response_code);
    rc_destroy(rad_config);
    goto end;
}
```

in above code `response_code` is and integer and that function only excepts pointer or we can say address of variable.
but i want to pass the int value of response_code say 25 not its address.
how can i do this..????

Comment: why ? why can't you create a `int resp_code = 25;` and pass `&resp_code` to the function?

Comment: goto is bad, really bad!

Comment: @Phong, Not always bad. Depending on the whole function, this could be  an example of a good `goto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just cast `response_code` to an `int*`, but I think you are going down the path to pain - if the method expects a pointer you should give it a pointer.
(the goto is a signpost that points to pain as well).

e.g.

```
if (rc_avpair_add(rad_config, &send, PW_FS_RESPONSE_CODE,(int*)response_code, -1, PW_FS_PEC) == NULL)
```